# How to Copy/Clone a Job via Groovy in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to copy an existing Jenkins job and rename it in the same folder using Groovy. 
In addition, I would like to do a search and replace a word within git "polling ignores commits in certain paths" message box.

Is it possible and if so how can it be done?

Answer (score 4):

I was needing to solve a similar problem, and I found this [groovy sample for copying all the jobs in a view](https://www.rodrigoasensio.com/blog/how-to-copy-all-the-jenkins-jobs-programmatically/).

```
import hudson.model.*

def viewName = "product-build-dev"
def search = "-dev"
def replace = "-prod"

def view = Hudson.instance.getView(viewName)

/* now you copy all jobs of the view copy all projects of a view */
for(item in view.getItems()) {

  /* create the new project name */
  newName = item.getName().replace(search , replace)

  /* now copy the job */
  def job = Hudson.instance.copy(item, newName)
  job.save()

}
```

I just realized I didn't answer the whole question. Looking...