# How to copy Jenkins Jobs from one folder to another using groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I don't seem to be able to find a way to copy jobs from one folder to another using groovy script in Jenkins.

Any pointers would be really helpful

Comment: Can't mark as duplicate as the other answer has not been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This S/O post will show you [you how to copy jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51957236/598141)

This S/O post will show you [how to move jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46892171/598141).

Essentially, it's either :

`Items.copy(item, newName)`

or

`Items.move(item, folder)`

Comment: Hey @devops, did the answer help solve the problem?